# [0x https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote? and MultiHop

Tags: 0x

i'm trying to swap two token on BSC  WBNB for BUSD or else with https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote? . All transactions work fine when 0x selected a simple DEX or Multi DEX but failed when 0x selected a multihop. I work with a fork ganache of the BSC, if somebody have a idea ?  Thanks in advance !